# How to automate Web Scraping with R from a password protected website?

Tags: r, web-scraping, automation, web-search, protected-resource

I'm very new in web scraping and automation and for this reason I ask if you can give me a hand with this problem:
I have a dataframe with information about several spanish companies. I want to identify the company sector, extracting CNAE information, and the company size. I want to extract this information from the SABI database, which requires the user and password information (I have a user).
How can I extract the CNAE and company size information from this webpage and add to my current dataframe as new columns?

Thank you very much ;)

Comment: Probably Rselenium

Comment: Iy would be useful if you could provide the link of the website you are trying to webscrape. We could provide a solution.